# Weird Yosemite Behaviour

Tags: macos, login, reboot

I've got a new MacBook Air, no issues for last month or so.
Recently I've noticed some weird behaviour in yosemite.

For a start:
These are my settings [image: settings]:

Yet this is my login screen: [image: login screen]

Notice I specifically set Don't show Input menu and Don't show Restart/Reboot, yet they appear on the login screen.

Another thing, When I log in the menu bar shows as black for about 5 seconds and then pops into view. If I change to dark menu bar this doesnt happen.

Finally, it sometimes reboots by itself only during login. I've ran it for hours building/compiling iOS apps without issue, playing games etc.... however the odd time (especially seems prone if I change the wallpaper) on restart the login menu shows and after entering my password the screen turns black and restarts (chime and all).

After the restart I notice that the login screen no longer shows a blurred version of my custom wallpaper but instead the default yosemite wallpaper.
I had the computer in with Apple for a battery replacement, and mentioned this to them, they tested the machine and found no issues...
Given that it's all reproducible I think it's a software flaw with 
Yosemite, but its really really weird.

by the way, I checked the console logs (I'm a developer and not afraid to diagnose stuff) and there is nothing in there regarding the weird reboot on login.

Anyway, as you can see pretty weird, any ideas? I was thinking of just updating to El Capitan to see if this goes away? I'm running 10.10.3.

Comment: It has not accepted your settings. Open the Disk Utility and run the disk permissions repair.

Comment: Did that already (should have mentioned) no joy.